# SharePoint WSP slow deploy time from Visual Studio

Tags: development, 2016, farm-solution, visual-studio-2015

I have a fairly large solution divided on 24 SharePoint projects in order to reduce deploy time during development. However, even with this careful architecture (being careful not to put too many SharePoint items in a project) deploy time + time to load the page is around 4 minutes. Dev machine is virtual machine with 4 core CPU and 16GB of RAM, disk is not SSD.

What deploy time + page load time do you consider acceptable? In other words, what deploy time makes you intervene, either by scaling up hardware or refactoring your solution? I know this is subjective to each developer but I want to hear opinions to draw the conclusion what would the mean time be.